# Python regular expression how to deal with multiple back slash \

Tags: python, regex, text

I’m dealing with text data and having problem erasing multiple back slashes.
I found out that using .sub works quite well. So I coded as below to erase back slash+r n t f v

```
temp_string = re.sub(r"[\t\n\r\f\v]"," ",string)
```

However, the code above can’t deal with the string below.

```
string = '\\\\r \\\\nLove the filtered water and crushed ice in the door.'
```

So coded as this:

```
temp_string = re.sub(r"[\\\\t\\\\n\\\\r\\\\f\\\\v]"," ",string)
temp_string
```

But it’s showing result like this..

**I don’t know why this happens.**

Erasing all the v,f,n and so on..

I found out using `.replace(“\\\\r”,” ”)` works!
However,in this way, i should go like..

```
.replace(“\\\\r”,” ”)

.replace(“\\\r”,” ”)

.replace(“\\r”,” ”)

.replace(“\r”,” ”)

.replace(“\\\\t”,” ”)

…
```

I’m pretty sure there’d be better way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't define a sequence of characters inside a character class**. Character classes are meant to match a single character. So, `[\\\\t\\\\n\\\\r\\\\f\\\\v]` is equal to `[\\tnrfv]` and matches either a backslash, or `t`, `n`, `r`, `f` or `v` letters.

To match a sequence of chars, you need to use them one by one. To match a `\n` two-char string you need to use `\\n` pattern (`r'\\n'`). If you need to match either `\n` or `\v` texts you would need to use either `\\n|\\v`, `(?:\\n|\\v)` or better `\\[nv]`.

So, if you want to match a backslash followed with a letter from the `rtnfv` char set, or `"\t"` (TAB), `"\n"` (line feed), `"\r"` (carriage return), `"\f"` (form feed) or `"\v"` (vertical tab) chars you can use

```
r'\\[rtnfv]|[\t\n\r\f\v]'
r'(?:\\[rtnfv]|[\t\n\r\f\v])'
r'(?:\\[rtnfv]|[\t\n\r\f\v])+'
```

The last one matches one or more consecutive occurrences of the patterns that may be mixed with each other.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! and thanks for the code sir. It worked with r'\[rtnfv]|[\t\n\r\f\v]' ! However, when I use the code below, it's showing a bit strange result.. string = '\\\\r \\\\nLove the filtered water \rand crushed ice in the door.' new_string = re.sub(r"\[rtnfv]|[tnrfv]"," ",string) # [tnrfv] new_string >>> '\\ \\ Love the filtered water \rand crushed ice in the door.' the result shows that the [tnrfv] couldn't deal with "\rand". maybe should I go with \\n|\\v, (?:\\n|\\v) style than \[nv]..? But don't know exactly why.. just know the result.

Comment: @data_minD Please see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/1qop5a). What is not clear in this code and results?

Comment: Thanks for sharing code sir. I found that using print() and the actual value is different. you can check in this url: https://ideone.com/TKutpc

Comment: @data_minD `print()` shows the *actual* string value, the literal text. `\r` is not erased, it is a line break symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Since escape characters are not the same as characters with a backslash before them, you will need to define a mapping for the escape characters you want to replace.

```py
string = '\\\\r \\\\\nLove the \nfiltered \\twater \\and crushed ice in the door.'

esc_map = {'\\n': '\n',
           '\\t': '\t',
           '\\r': '\r'}

# replace characters that should be escaped characters
for key, value in esc_map.items():
    string = string.replace(key, value)

# group escape character that might have backslashes prefixed 
re_str = r'\\*({})'.format(r'|'.join(esc_map.values()))
# remove extra backslashes
string = re.sub(re_str,r'\1',string)
# replace an escape character with a space
string = re.sub(re_str,r' ',string)
```